# Не прямоугольная область поиска HTTP-запроса на геокодирование в YANDEX API

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Можно ли задать не прямоугольную область поиска? В документации вижу query параметры `ll`, `spn`, `bbox`. Но как я понял ими можно только задать только  прямоугольник.  Однако моя область поиска это многоугольник:

```
 geometry={{
              type: "Polygon",
              coordinates: [
                [
                  [30.324175, 59.843914],
                  [30.339396, 59.844072],
                  [30.347077, 59.842431],
                  [30.355538, 59.842664],
                  [30.3675, 59.844154],
                  [30.381282, 59.8175],
                  [30.324002, 59.817543],
                ],
              ],
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Геокодер занимается поиском адреса по координатам или наоборот. Выборка по области, даже прямоугольной – не его конёк. Яндекс не реализовал возможности геокодирования по полигонам.

Альтернативный вариант – поиск в прямоугольнике в [JS API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/concepts/About.html), а после проверка полученных ответов при помощи [geoQuery](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.html) на попадание в ваш полигон, как в [примере поиска зоны доставки](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones).